# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in iOS6 only when using Storyboard and segue

Tags: ios6, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I am using storyboard in my app. And I am using the code below to navigate from a UITableView to another UIView.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNextView" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showNextView"])
    {
        AnotherViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        // do something with the destination.
    }
}
```

There are no problem at at all when I use iOS 5 and iOS 5.1 simulator. But I get an error as below when I use iOS 6 simulator.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10)

in line

```
0x1588098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
```

in file

> libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:

Even I make AnotherViewController to be a pure blank view. I am still getting the same error.

Thanks

Comment: I fixed my issue. We can't use -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath in iOS 6 for some reason.

Now that works fine.

Comment: I used the wrong method. Should use -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: